# 3 particles A,B and C are situated at the vertices..

Tags: vectors, kinematics

I had this question

"3 particles A,B and C are situated at the vertices of an equilateral triangle ABC of side d at t=0. Each particle moves with a constant speed v. A always has its velocity along AB, B along BC and C along CA. At what time will the particles meet ?"

In this my book says that the distance travelled by the particle let's say A (it will be the same for all three) will travel a distance AO ( O being the centroid where all three will meet) .

In my book value of AO is given to be

AO = $\frac{2}{3} \sqrt{d^2 - (\frac{d}{2})^2}$ = $\frac{d}{\sqrt{3}}$

The only thing I couldn't understand was that how did expression come AO = $\frac{2}{3} \sqrt{d^2 - (\frac{d}{2})^2}$

Can somebody please give me an explanation for this .
Regards

Comment: The question isn't making much sense. Are you sure you have posted it correctly?

Comment: @Vizag If the particles are really moving such that the speed vector of A points towards B and so on, then they will travel a distance greater than the straight-line length of AO.

Comment: Your question is how the distance traveled is AO, or how $AO = \frac{2}{3} \sqrt{d^2 - (\frac{d}{2})^2}$, if it is the second one, that is standard property of equilateral triangle.

Comment: Try searching for "pursuit curve" and "equilateral triangle".

Comment: The question is correct . It's from I.E. IRODOV

Comment: Somebody please help....

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'm not sure where that expression came from either.
But if you look at:

[image]

You'll notice that $AOE$ is a right angled 30-60-90 triangle so $AO=\frac{2}{3}\sqrt{3}AE=\frac{1}{\sqrt{3}}AC$ which is what you wanted.

I guess I'll add this for completeness:

To finish off the question, we note that if the particles were travelling in straight lines, the distance to the center of the equilateral triangle becomes $$\sqrt{(d-v\Delta t)^2+\frac{1}{3}d^2}$$ so $\frac{\mathrm d}{\mathrm dt}(\text{distance to center})=-\frac{\sqrt{3}}2$. Since the distance to the center is $\frac{\sqrt{3}}{2}$ of the sidelength $d$, we know that the time taken is $\cfrac{3}{2}\cfrac{s}{v}$ for particles of speed $v$ starting at distance $s$ from each other.